# ImageMagick - Drawing a complex image with many (lots of) squares

Tags: imagemagick

I want to draw many shapes in an image created with ImageMagick through the command line, so empty from the start. I wish to create the empty image in memory, draw shapes in it and when all is done save to a file. I don't know how to pipe the commands so that they are all executed before the file is saved.

So basically, here is the flow I wish to achieve:

- create an image
- loop in shape definitions and draw each shape in the image
- save the image to disk

**Edited:** I am trying to generate an image of random square patterns using bash script. For this purpose I generated a white image of size 1280x720px and pasted black squares onto it. These squares have random size, position and rotation. Here I attached my image https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BypRKoRnoTbbWkMyLXJDYl9xT3c I succeeded to get. I need help to make these squares not to overlap on each other. I want to paste them only in empty spaces of the background image.
I am working on a Linux based system.

Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# PX    position of squares on X-axis
# PY    position of squares on Y-axis
# ROT   rotation angle of squres

# generating background image of size 1280x720
convert -size 1260x720 canvas:white  bg.jpg

# generating 100 squares of random size in between 20x20 px
for (( count=1; count <= 1000; count++ ))
do

X=$((RANDOM%10+10))
convert -size "$X"x"$X" canvas:black  square.jpg

# copying squares on background image

PX=$((RANDOM%1260+1))
PY=$((RANDOM%720+1))

ROT=$((RANDOM%90+0))

convert \( bg.jpg \) \( square.jpg -background none -rotate "$ROT" \)  -geometry +"$PX"+"$PY" -composite bg.jpg


done
```

Comment: Please edit your post your code so we can help you

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and add your code so we have something to work with. Please also clarify your environment - Linux, OSX, Windows?

Comment: I edited my question and shared my script that can generate random square pattern but they are overlapping. I want them to paste only in empty spaces of the background image.

Comment: That's better - I have voted to reopen your question but more folks need to do so before it will happen. In the meantime, you should definitely move to PNG rather than decompressing and recompressing lossy JPEG's 1000 times.

Comment: That is a good suggestion

Comment: This quite an interesting question. One way to do it that works, is to generate your square and rotate it immediately before you save it and get its dimensions after rotation. Then enter a second, inner loop, that crops pieces out of your background image the same size at your random locations. Then exit that inner loop when all the cropped pixels are white which means there is enough background white space to accommodate the rotated square, then composite the square in and go to your next iteration.

Comment: Also, rather than my earlier suggestion of PNG format, it is actually better to use MPC (Magick Pixel Cache) format - just replace PNG with MPC all the way through and then at the very end `convert bg.mpc bg.png`.

Comment: Thank you for voting up. I also posted my problem on ImageMagick forum and I got help. You can check here http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=30734 . It helped me on what I was looking for but there must be easy way to do it.

Comment: My result is here... http://thesetchells.com/bg.png

Comment: It looks great. That's what I'm looking for. Can you show me your script please?

Comment: I would prefer that the question is reopened rather than going against the wishes of folks who decided it should be closed. Maybe they will reconsider - @Unheilig ?

Comment: Please consider maybe re-opening this question @Batty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a trial-and-error type of solution that works pretty well:

```
#!/bin/bash

# PX    position of squares on X-axis
# PY    position of squares on Y-axis
# ROT   rotation angle of squres

# generating background image of size 1260x720
convert -size 1260x720 canvas:white  bg.mpc

# Get quantum range (likely 255, or 65535)
QR=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:quantumrange]" info:)

# generating 100 squares of random size in between 20x20 px
for (( count=1; count <= 1000; count++ ))
do
   X=$((RANDOM%10+10))
   ROT=$((RANDOM%90+0))
   # Create square, and rotate. Work out space needed to draw it
   w=$(convert -size "$X"x"$X" canvas:black -background none -rotate $ROT +repage -format "%w" -write info:- square.mpc)
   echo "DEBUG: Square $count is ${X}x${X} rotated $ROT, making ${w}x${w}"

   # Keep choosing random places in image till we find big enough hole
   n=1
   while :; do
      PX=$((RANDOM%(1260-w)))
      PY=$((RANDOM%(720-w)))
      echo "DEBUG: Attempt $n - trying at $PX,$PY"
      # Crop out the corresponding square and check it is all white, if so, ok
      min=$(convert bg.mpc -crop ${w}x${w}+${PX}+${PY} -colorspace gray -format "%[min]" info:)
      [ $min -eq $QR ] && break
      ((n=n+1))
   done
   convert bg.mpc square.mpc -geometry +"$PX"+"$PY" -composite bg.mpc
done
convert bg.mpc bg.png
```

[image]

Here is a second run:

[image]

I have done it in `bash` since that is the way you tried - however, it would be much faster in C++/PHP as it could be done in memory rather than having to keep writing the squares to disk between compositing.

**Sample Output**

```
DEBUG: Square 1 is 15x15 rotated 15, making 21x21
DEBUG: Attempt 1 - trying at 900,360
DEBUG: Square 2 is 13x13 rotated 36, making 21x21
DEBUG: Attempt 1 - trying at 87,499
DEBUG: Square 3 is 15x15 rotated 22, making 21x21
DEBUG: Attempt 1 - trying at 324,194
DEBUG: Square 4 is 14x14 rotated 48, making 22x22
DEBUG: Attempt 1 - trying at 469,203
DEBUG: Square 5 is 16x16 rotated 53, making 24x24
DEBUG: Attempt 1 - trying at 1104,328
DEBUG: Square 6 is 18x18 rotated 27, making 26x26
DEBUG: Attempt 1 - trying at 541,385
DEBUG: Square 7 is 15x15 rotated 0, making 15x15
DEBUG: Attempt 1 - trying at 377,432
DEBUG: Square 8 is 19x19 rotated 69, making 27x27
DEBUG: Attempt 1 - trying at 108,647
DEBUG: Square 9 is 14x14 rotated 64, making 20x20
DEBUG: Attempt 1 - trying at 95,238
DEBUG: Square 10 is 12x12 rotated 45, making 18x18
DEBUG: Attempt 1 - trying at 764,588
DEBUG: Square 11 is 18x18 rotated 3, making 20x20
DEBUG: Attempt 1 - trying at 1048,101
DEBUG: Square 12 is 17x17 rotated 77, making 23x23
DEBUG: Attempt 1 - trying at 1086,316
DEBUG: Attempt 2 - trying at 915,554
DEBUG: Square 13 is 19x19 rotated 5, making 23x23
...
```

It would probably be faster to sort the sizes of the squares and place the largest ones first so there are fewer re-calculations due to misses as it gets successively harder to place the squares.

There are probably cleverer algorithms too, but I may be lazy ;-)

I have made a little animation of how it works below. Good placements of a square show up green, position clashes show up red.

[image]

Comment: Wow its great. I was not expecting such a nice explanation. Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure - glad it worked out for you Good luck with your project, and remember to come back if you get stuck - questions, and answers, are free.